# Modal not working properly once it is closed

Tags: react-native

I have added the above reusable code to show Modal and close the Modal when clicked outside of that Modal, when I click on a button the Modal is shown and when I click outside of that Modal it gets closed till here it is working properly but again when I click on a button to open Modal, the Modal is not shown, can anyone tell me what mistake I have made.

```
import React, { FunctionComponent, useState } from 'react';
import { Modal, FlatList,TouchableWithoutFeedback } from 'react-native';

interface Props {
  visible: boolean;
  onClose: () => void;
}
const BottomSheet: FunctionComponent<Props> = (props) => {
  const [showBottomSheet,setBottomSheet]=useState(true);

  return (
    showBottomSheet && (
    <Modal animationType={ANIMATIONS.SlideType} transparent={true} visible={props.visible}>
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={()=> setBottomSheet(false)}>
         <View style={Styles.Container}></View>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
      <View style={Styles.container}>
        <View style={Styles.headerContainer}>
          <View style={[Styles.header, Styles.directionRow]}>
            <View>
              <Text style={Styles.headerText}>{Strings.addNew}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={Styles.iconContainer}>
              <IMIcon
                name={cancel}
                size={18}
                iconsStyle={Styles.closeButton}
                IconClick={props.onClose}
              />
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
        <View style={Styles.viewContainer}>
          <SafeAreaView>
            <FlatList
              horizontal={false}
              data={props.navData}
              renderItem={renderActions}
              keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
            />
          </SafeAreaView>
        </View>
      </View>
    </Modal>
   )
  );

};
```

This is the other file where I am using the above reusable component

```
const [showBottomSheet, setShowBottomSheet] = useState(false);
  const hideBottomSheet = () => {
    setShowBottomSheet(false);
  };


 <View style={Styles.profileContainer}>
    <AddNewButton
      onButtonPress={() => {
        setShowBottomSheet(true);
      }}
      buttonStyle={Styles.plusButton}
      iconObject={{
        iconName: plus,
        iconSize: Sizes.plusLargeSize,
        iconStyle: Styles.Icon,
      }}
    />
    <BottomSheet
      visible={showBottomSheet}
      onClose={hideBottomSheet}
    />
  </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have duplicite state.
When you close it, you set internal state to `false` and never set it to `true`.

Remove internal state and call `onClose` instead and it will work just fine.

Edit: code sample:

```
const BottomSheet: FunctionComponent<Props> = (props) => {

  if (!props.visible) return null;

  return (
    <Modal animationType={ANIMATIONS.SlideType} transparent={true} visible={props.visible}>
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={props.onClose}>
     ...
```

Comment: Is it possible to close the Modal without using props on <TouchableWithoutFeedback> as I want to add the logic in this reusable component itself

Comment: Check out how to use `useImperativeHandle` (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useimperativehandle)